# How to open html file that links with images and stuffs in mvc

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have html files in another directory which links with some JavaScript, images and CSS. I want to open that html file in my site.  I used the return File method in my controller action as shown below:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return File(Server.MapPath("~") + "index.html", "text/html");
}
```

But, it could not open the images and JavaScript that are linked to that in the `.html` file.

What is the proper solution? I'm using ASP.net MVC 4.

Thanks, I'm still a beginner at this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand what you are trying to do here, you should not return an HTML file in the controller action but rather generate the view of the index page. If you are new to MVC you might benefit from reading more about Model-View-Controller pattern and when to apply it.

If all you are trying to do is serve a static HTML file, just let IIS serve that file and point the browser at the URL of that file directly. (i.e. Where it is stored on your web site).

If you want to have some logic dynamically linking to some static file, there are many ways to do it (both on the server and on the client), one of them would be to calculate the correct URL and redirect the user by returning a `Redirect()` operation from your controller action.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. i tried generating the view of the index page, all is fine but the javascript files dont load at all, they're all linked correctly but it just wouldnt load...... thats where im stuck........pls help

Comment: What i mean is, by generating the view of the index page, i got the sourcecode of its html exactly same as the original index.html file, however, nothing shows up.

Comment: When viewing the page on Chrome or FireFox - Press F12 and go to the developer tools and navigate to the network tab then refresh the page. What errors do you see? (red lines)